# Using regex to match the ip adress of the process using netstat -nb python

Tags: python, regex, netstat

I am using python 3 and I am trying to get the ip address of the process, using netstat -nb. I managed to get using subprocess module the following string:

```
TCP 192.168.1.22:65477 212.55.188.116:443 ESTABLISHED\n [WinStore.App.exe]
```

My question is, how can i get using regex the ip address - "212.55.188.116".

Comment: what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I don't think "212.55.188.116" is a process.

Answer (score 0):

If the lengths are consistent with the IP Your trying to search you could use something along the lines of:

```
((\d{3}.)\d{2}.(\d{3}.){2}\d{3})
```